# Error while mapping fetched objects with ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contentful

### Problem

I want to fetch articles from contentflow but this is the error I am getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
(anonymous function)
E:/Project-VidM/client/src/components/Blog/index.js:21
  18 | 
  19 |   const Articles = article.map((entry) => {
  20 |       return(
> 21 |        <div className="entry" key={entry.sys.id}>
     | ^  22 |        <h1>{entry.fields.title}</h1>
  23 |        <img src={entry.fields.featuredImage.sys} />
  24 |        {entry.fields.body.data}
View compiled
```

### This is my React Code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import * as contentful from 'contentful';

const BlogComponent = () => {
    const [article, setArticle] = useState([]);

    const client = contentful.createClient({
    space: 'xxxxxxxx' ,
    accessToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    });
    
    useEffect(() => {
       client.getEntries()
            .then((res) => {
                setArticle([res.items]);
            })
    }, [])

   const Articles = article.map((entry) => {
       return(
        <div className="entry" key={entry.sys.id}>
        <h1>{entry.fields.title}</h1>
        <img src={entry.fields.featuredImage} />
        {entry.fields.body.data}
        </div>
       )
    }) 
    return (
       <div>
           {Articles}
       </div>
    )
}

export default BlogComponent
```

When I do a console.log on `res.items`, I get the following output:

[image: contentful]

How do I map over the particular fields?

Answer (score 1):

in console.log `res.items` is an array and you are putting it inside another array

it should be `setArticle(res.items)` instead of `setArticle([res.items])`

Comment: Thank you but doing that gives me the following error: ```  objects are not valid as a react child (found: object with keys {}). if you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.  ```

Comment: what is inside **entry.fields.body.data** ? looks like its an object instead of string or number @SubhankarChowdhury